# add a tracking code to the first instance of a link in each line of a CSV file

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to add a tracking code to the first instance of a link in each line of a csv file using perl. How could I do that?

example

input:

```
ID, text1, link1, text2, text3, link2
1234, something, http://www.example.com/a/b/c, "lorem", "ipsum", http://www.example.com/image.gif
1235, something, http://www.example.com/dddd, "lorem", "ipsum", http://www.example.com/image.gif
1236, something, http://www.example.com/e/f/g/h, "lorem", "ipsum", http://www.example.com/image.gif
```

output:

```
ID, text1, link1, text2, text3, link2
1234, something, http://www.example.com/a/b/c?tracking_code=1&tr2=2, "lorem", "ipsum", http://www.example.com/image.gif
1235, something, http://www.example.com/dddd?tracking_code=1&tr2=2, "lorem", "ipsum", http://www.example.com/image.gif
1236, something, http://www.example.com/e/f/g/h?tracking_code=1&tr2=2, "lorem", "ipsum", http://www.example.com/image.gif
```

Comment: **Don't try to deal with the lines of input as a string.**  Read each one in, process it into its component fields, modify the field in question, and recreate the fields as an output string.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) for proper handling of CSV files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my $file = 'file.csv';

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({allow_whitespace => 1,
                            eol => $/,
                           }) or die 'Text::CSV'->error_diag;
open my $CSV, '<', $file or die $!;

my $header = $csv->getline($CSV);
while (my $row = $csv->getline($CSV)) {
    $row->[2] .= '?tracking_code=1&tr=2';
    $csv->print(*STDOUT{IO}, $row);
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag;
```

Comment: Of course, URLs are URLs and not plain strings. Appending a query string could produce weird results. The `URI` module includes some support that could help avoid this. But this may not be an issue if the URLs in the 3rd row never contain queries or fragments.

Comment: 'use Text::CSV;' throws an error on my console, can't locate the module. Even if I can load it on my computer, I need a solution which also works on a standard server installation. What do you think?